# With Twitter's mounting troubles, when is the time to jump and where to?

Tags: social-media, networking

Twitter has been useful for keeping an eye on relevant research and ocasionally for a bit of peer support through the PhD journey, as well as for sharing some work-related links, announcements, observations, a bit of fun, etc.

I think lots of people have jumped to mastodon and threads, but I haven't yet bothered to go there properly, mostly because I've been furiously writing up my thesis for the last few months.  However, it seems like academia is slow to move (if conference and journal reviewing web portals are anything to go by), so I expect a lot of the organisations and people I follow to keep tweeting for the foreseeable future.

Do you have any advice about how to manage this transition - has academic social media already become too splintered to be of use?  Is it worth sticking it out with X, or should I set up accounts on some of the other platforms?  It seems to be a tradeoff between investing time in updating and checking different profiles versus a quiet life but missing out on some useful leads.  Just to be clear, I'm not trying to make a name for myself online, just to be in the loop for interesting developments and those accidental dicoveries of interesting people or work.

Comment: This is strange, I have never followed twitter or any other social media to keep track of advances in my field (I guess I know a very small handful of researchers who have blogs).

Comment: Go to mastadon maybe, it's hart to switch since you kinda need your entire network to switch too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two main contenders to what used to be twitter are now [Mastodon](https://joinmastodon.org/) or [Bluesky](https://blueskyweb.xyz/blog/5-19-2023-user-faq).
The bulk of the academic community seems to have tried Mastodon first (to some extent) and is now more interested in Bluesky.
Bluesky (from what I've heard) is closest to the original twitter experience and philosophy, while Mastodon has a non-profit, more DIY philosophy (and more protective of its users e.g. against harassment).

There are also alternative networks, for example I've been on [Linkedin](https://www.linkedin.com/) for an while and it recently got a surge of new academic accounts; also, [Researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/) remains very useful to find out new papers, but not necessarily the latest ones.

In an ideal world, and in my opinion, we'd all go to Mastodon, but it might not be the least-effort option at the moment.